# How do handle menu organization (taxonomy) in EE4?

Tags: ee4, taxonomy

I've been using EE2 + Taxonomy for years. Great combo. But Taxonomy might not be available for EE4. I've been spoiled for so many years, I've never thought of how to organize my menus without it.

How do you guys handle menu organization?

For example, I have channel Cars. In Cars I have entries Civic, Versa, Versa (Sedan), Mustang. I want a Cars local menu with items: Mustang, Civic, Versa, and Versa (Sedan) as a child under Versa.

Sorry if ignorant, but I've done this so many years with Taxonomy, and now I'm not sure of EE4's ideal native solutions, or whether there are other good addon solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options, but three you might like to consider are:

- using categories and an add-on such as [Category Construct](https://buzzingpixel.com/software/category-construct)
- using a dedicated menu add-on such as [NavEE](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/navee)
- using [Low Reorder](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/low-reorder) - which is sort of a hybrid of the two above

HTH

Comment: NavEE looks great, trying that.